# Create new data frame column based on conditioned column names in R

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, concatenation, tibble

I am working with a large dataset. This dataset has a column with a reference code and other columns whose values are TRUE or FALSE.
I'm trying to create a new column that collects concatenated (or as a list) the names of the columns whose value is equal to TRUE.
A simplification of the dataframe would be something like:

```
data <- data.frame( Reference = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005"),
                 Column A = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
                 Column B = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                 Column C = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))
data
```

The expected result would be something like:

| Reference | Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0001 | TRUE | FALSE | TRUE | Column A, Column C |
| 0002 | TRUE | TRUE | FALSE | Column A, Column B |
| 0003 | FALSE | TRUE | TRUE | Column B, Column C |
| 0004 | TRUE | FALSE | FALSE | Column A |
| 0005 | FALSE | FALSE | TRUE | Column C |

I know how to create fields by concatenating values or column names but I don't know how to introduce the conditional so that it only takes the names of the columns whose value is TRUE.

Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` solution with `tidyr::unite()`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  mutate(unite(across(starts_with('Column'), ~ ifelse(.x, cur_column(), NA)),
               col = 'Column_D', sep = ', ', na.rm = TRUE))

#   Reference Column_A Column_B Column_C           Column_D
# 1       001     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE Column_A, Column_C
# 2       002     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE Column_A, Column_B
# 3       003    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE Column_B, Column_C
# 4       004     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE           Column_A
# 5       005    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE           Column_C
```

Answer (score 2):

Base R solution

```
data <- data.frame( Reference = c("001", "002", "003", "004", "005"),
                    Column_A = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE), 
                    Column_B = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
                    Column_C = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE))

L <- apply(data, 1, function(i) which(i == TRUE))
data$Column_D <- lapply(L, function(x) paste0(names(x), collapse = ", "))

#   Reference Column_A Column_B Column_C           Column_D
# 1       001     TRUE    FALSE     TRUE Column_A, Column_C
# 2       002     TRUE     TRUE    FALSE Column_A, Column_B
# 3       003    FALSE     TRUE     TRUE Column_B, Column_C
# 4       004     TRUE    FALSE    FALSE           Column_A
# 5       005    FALSE    FALSE     TRUE           Column_C
```

Comment: Or simply `apply(data[-1], 1, \(i)toString(names(which(i))))`

Answer (score 2):

Another `dplyr` option:

```r
data %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Column_D = toString(names(across(starts_with("Column")))[which(c_across(starts_with("Column")))]))

  Reference Column_A Column_B Column_C Column_D          
  <chr>     <lgl>    <lgl>    <lgl>    <chr>             
1 001       TRUE     FALSE    TRUE     Column_A, Column_C
2 002       TRUE     TRUE     FALSE    Column_A, Column_B
3 003       FALSE    TRUE     TRUE     Column_B, Column_C
4 004       TRUE     FALSE    FALSE    Column_A          
5 005       FALSE    FALSE    TRUE     Column_C
```